# Step Functions Dynamodb UpdateItem for all data using partial key value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

what is the best Step function pattern to solve the following use case:
I want to update (add a new attribute) for all data in a dynamodb table by deducing a value from partition key.

For example, say following is partition key pattern in my dynamodb table and I would like update (add a new attribute) each row with partial value from key.  For first row new value to be inserted would be 641, second row it would be 471.  Is it possible to use tasks via just DynamoDb Resource type UpdateItem or a lambda is must post scan?

partition key

```
UA641
UA471
UA688
UA352
UA1743
UA1297
UA1743
UA1302
UA1743
UA721
UA2657
UA2657
UA721
UA2657
UA402
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the keys then you could do it via Step Functions with UpdateItem directly.

But it's likely you don't know all the keys so you must Scan the entire table to obtain them.

My advice would be to use a Parallel Scan which breaks the tables into segments and call update item for each of those segments. The parallel scan will help avoid creating hot partitions while doing the job.

You could also rate limit it by inducing some sleep after each page you scan.

Comment: yes, it's going to be a scan operation.  Keys to update is a large number.  Will explore Parallel Scan with rate limit.